# What can we do when a close-reason requires an explanation?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, opinion-based

Suppose you have this question:

> Which is better: X or Y?

or

> What is the best way to do Z?

You could close it using the "opinion-based" close-reason. However, this is not very helpful for a person who wants to choose how to do some task.

You could answer it as follows:

> To decide what is better, you have to consider A, B and C.

The question may still be considered opinion-based, because ultimately your decision depends on your opinion on A, B and C. However, "A, B and C" is a vital piece of information, and attaching it to the question makes the world better.

To make it more general, you can close any question for any reason, but sometimes it's not clear how this reason applies. This (how a particular reason applies to the question) may be something obvious for experts but completely unclear to OP. This site was built specifically for accumulating such information, using answers (or, maybe more recently, comments).

Usually such information can fit in comments (e.g. "needs debugging details"), but sometimes not. Another close-reason for which a lengthy explanation may be required is "duplicate". Maybe for others too (see below).

What should we do?

---

I searched for closed questions on [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (because that's what I mostly care about); here are some examples where a more "explicit" treatment would have been better. I picked newest ones. I had to search through quite a lot to find ones which were closed, but whose close reason required nontrivial explanation.

1. [Are unit tests necessary for embedded C/C++ projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78197755/509868)
2. [What's the difference between threading libraries like pthreads and std::thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78194068/509868)
3. [Storing a song genres in just one byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78189315/509868)
4. [Boolean testing vs exception in stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78183004/509868)
5. [What is the algorithm for installing a library in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78175104/509868)

---

Here are some old questions which accumulated answers but were later closed. I picked most voted-for ones. Here, whether or not they are closed is not very important, but it still illustrates a point that close-worthy questions may also be answerable.

1. [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/145270/509868)
2. [Why have header files and .cpp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/333889/509868)
3. [Case-insensitive string comparison in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11635/509868)
4. [Do you (really) write exception safe code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1853243/509868)
5. [C/C++ include header file order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2762568/509868)

Comment: Note that one purpose of comments is to ["Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) so this is definitely the place for advice on how to fix questions to remove the close reason.

Comment: Sometimes, this information can't fit in comments. For example, if you need a piece of code to show what you are talking about. Comments can usually handle "missing debugging information" issues, but usually not "opinion-based" ones.

Comment: Why would that belong into comments in the first place? Close voters shouldn't need to show pieces of code to explain how the question can be improved. Similarly, what's there to explain about opinion-based? FWIW, most of the examples comments are misused to discuss and partially answer the question, not to offer advice on improving it. Such things don't fit well into comments *on purpose* - are you aware of that?

Comment: I agree that the way close voting is implemented, has mutated over time and today is used because too often the wrong close reason is hastily applied, sends off confusing and even misleading signals. It sucks. But the thing that sucks more is that so many questions need to be closed - because they were asked in complete ignorance of how the site works. There is just no salvaging possible there, it was dead on arrival. It is commendable that you try, but it is a fight you can't win. Such questions need to go to other websites, where discussion, back and forth and tutoring is possible.

Answer (score 10):

You post a comment. [That's what comments are there for.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - [...]
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - [...]

Critically, if you find that what you *think* you must post in a comment does not fit comfortably, this is a good indication it is *not* required information.

- If you need more than a comment to explain why a duplicate applies - well, most likely the duplicate target does not provide an answer. If it were, you would not have to cram a whole new answer into a comment.
- If you need more than a comment to explain the many ways a question needs improvement - well, it should already be obvious then. If it is not, the question likely is not salvageable to begin with.
- If you need more than a comment to post code to demonstrate something, or talk about the As, Bs and Cs, or to anyway post an answer that you know should not be an answer, or ... - well, you should accept that some content just does not belong on SO. That does not only apply to questions but also answers and comments.

Comment: I am trying to apply your points to my example, which I think requires a lengthy explanation on why it's opinion-based. First point — looks like I need to answer instead of closing. Second point — doesn't apply. Third point — says it's off-topic instead. Did I understand it right?

Comment: Or maybe you want to say that such examples don't exist, and comments are always enough to explain whatever needs to be explained? Or maybe it's sufficiently rare that they are not enough, and these cases are not worth bothering about?

Comment: @anatolyg "I am trying to apply your points to my example ..." Which example are you referring to? Your "Which is better: X or Y?" examples are pretty clearly opinion based as presented, I'm frankly not even sure what you would want to explain about that.

Comment: Yes, that was the example. I now see that our views are fundamentally different, and you probably can't provide an answer acceptable for me.

Comment: @anatolyg It might help if you would outline those views a bit, I guess. It's rather hard for me to say which things in the meta-question are just misconceptions about what the parts of SO are there for, or genuinely an attempt to use things differently.

Comment: @anatolyg if that’s the case, it may well be that there’s no answer you’ll find acceptable. These are fundamental aspects of how the site is intended to work, and it seems like those aspects are what you’re at odds with

Comment: If you find yourself writing a lengthy explanation for a proposed duplicate, this is a sign that the question actually just needs more focus.

Answer (score 5):

When you're voting to close a question, it's because you find an issue. People could find the same issue as you even without a comment.

In your case, it's easy to understand for both of your examples that they are opinion-based, so we don't need to explain what is opinion-based there.

In the case of a typo for example, I most of the time see it's a typo thanks to comments or because someone uses this:

[image]

In fact, the "Other - add comment" is partially what you want. If the reason is not clear, you can write it yourself. It will be showed to the OP that will be able to answer to the issue reported and probably improve the post. But I don't think "Other" is necessary here; comments are made for this.

Answer (score 5):

### Subjective questions

> However, this is not very helpful for a person who wants to choose how to do some task.

This isn't our concern. One of the consequences of Stack Overflow not being a discussion forum, is that the purpose is not specifically to "help" the OP. **The purpose is to answer a question** that fits into a searchable reference Q&A library which fits within that library's scope. For Stack Overflow, we have chosen to exclude unqualified "best way" queries because they generate more heat than light. We can't weigh subjective factors on others' behalf, and we also *don't consider the OP's subjective weighting more important* than anyone else's.

> The question may still be considered opinion-based, because ultimately your decision depends on your opinion on A, B and C. However, "A, B and C" is a vital piece of information, and attaching it to the question makes the world better.

No; attaching it to a question *that directly solicits* that kind of information makes the world better.

To make a question like this objectively answerable in the format, it needs to be redesigned. There are three main approaches to this:

1. Skip the "best way" part entirely, and just open the floor for any reasonable approach (as long as this doesn't make the question too unfocused).
2. Choose a single objective criterion by which solutions may be judged (for example, runtime or memory usage).
3. Limit the solutions ahead of time to a specific closed set, and ask to know *what criteria are relevant* for making the decision.

In the latter case, an answer like you describe could be appropriate. Ideally it would give detail along the lines of "solution X tends to require less scratch disk space than solution Y in cases where A and C are within certain parameters", or "solution Y can avoid recalculating the B heuristic, giving better runtime performance when that heuristic is computationally expensive".

### Explaining close votes

Use the comments. That's part of what they're for. Absolutely do not ever write an answer because you think there's a problem with how the question is asked. **The point of closing questions is explicitly to prevent the answer section from being used**. The fact that there is a problem with the question is a reason not to answer it. That is in fact the defining feature of "problem" in this context. When close reasons were chosen, and refined over the years, all of this was explicitly for the purpose of communicating the reasons not to answer questions.

> Usually such information can fit in comments (e.g. "needs debugging details"), but sometimes not.

You get 600 characters for a comment - that's quite a lot. It's enough that I can fit copy-paste feedback like:

```
Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here
that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come
out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/)
and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase
it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where
you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does
something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect
something*), and don't understand why.
```

with multiple links and a detailed explanation of what is expected in order for a question to have appropriately narrowed focus and include necessary "debugging" details (I continue to insist that questions like this are no longer actually about debugging once they meet standards).

In some cases I can follow up with a more tailored comment that points out specific things to try isolating or removing, so as to determine where the problem is occurring. Or I might, following the Socratic method, ask pointed questions about exactly what OP expects to observe at certain key points in the code's execution. This is normally quite easy to do within 600 characters.

The same thing applies for every other close reason, and for every other common category of bad question (these categories are themselves subjective, and certainly don't map 1:1 with close reasons, but it's still vanishingly rare that a question should be closed for a custom reason).

You shouldn't need to show multi-line code in order to demonstrate what is wrong with a question. If OP didn't already provide code to point at, writing your own is certainly not going to help at. If there is code to point at, do so: "When you debug the code, is the block starting with `if (foo) {` actually entered?" If you can't readily do this, *that's the first real problem* with the question: it does not have a properly *minimal* reproducible example.

### Some specific examples

> I had to search through quite a lot to find ones which were closed, but whose close reason required nontrivial explanation.

**None of these are tricky**. There may have been a lot of comment discussion, but that's because people are in general bad at avoiding forum-mode discussion when they are given a free-form text input. Let's look at the first three C++ questions for example:

> Are unit tests necessary for embedded C/C++ projects?

The title question is subjective because there is no concrete way to define "necessary". The body "asks" (really, *doubts*) whether certain "complex things" could in principle be unit-tested. There's nothing of substance there; the kind of "thing" in question isn't properly specified, nor is the reason for doubt explained. Trivially, complex systems are composed of smaller parts. The last line asks "what everyone thinks"; i.e. it tries to treat the site as the discussion forum that it isn't.

**Absolutely none of that is the slightest bit difficult to explain**, and most of it doesn't really need explanation. The reason the comment section is long is because people are treating the comment section as a discussion forum. **The only useful comments there are the ones suggesting better places to ask the question.** Most of them seem to be trying to answer "why are unit tests in general necessary?", which is far too broad of a question, and still somewhat subjective. There might be something along the lines of "what is the purpose of unit tests?" already available that could, at a stretch, have been used as a duplicate, or linked as a reference.

> What's the difference between threading libraries like pthreads and std::thread?

This *clearly* needs more focus. In general, "what's the difference between X and Y" questions are rarely suitable, since they can't really be answered *other than* answering "what's X" and also answering "what's Y", which is two separate questions. The OP is looking for multiple comparisons, and details about how each tool works. **It doesn't require seven comments to explain this** - so it's not surprising that the comments overlap. They're also all quite a bit shorter than the limit.

> Storing a song genres in just one byte

The OP is trying to design a system and doesn't have clear requirements for that system - only a vague idea. The comments offer some critique of *that idea* - this is derailing, because the comments should criticize *the presentation of the question*. Even if we take the one design idea for granted, it devolves into three clearly separate questions: one about encoding, one about decoding, and one about searching for matches. None of those is clearly stated, and if they were, they would likely be duplicates.

**Even including the meta-commentary about the existing comments, the above paragraph is shorter than 600 characters**.

I hope by now that the pattern is obvious. The problem you are imagining, wherein explaining the problem with the question takes too much space for the comments, simply doesn't exist.